# How Can My Discord.js Bot welcome new people to the server?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make it so the bot Will Auto Welcome new members on multiple servers, this is the code I have currently and it doesn't come up with an error but it doesn't work

````
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    const guild = member.guild;
    if (!newUsers[guild.id]) newUsers[guild.id] = new Discord.Collection();
    newUsers[guild.id].set(member.id, member.user);
  
    if (newUsers[guild.id].size > 10) {
      const userlist = newUsers[guild.id].map(u => u.toString()).join(" ");
      guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "general").send("Welcome our new users!\n" + userlist);
      newUsers[guild.id].clear();
    }
  });
  
  client.on("guildMemberRemove", (member) => {
    const guild = member.guild;
    if (newUsers[guild.id].has(member.id)) newUsers.delete(member.id);
  });```
````

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Jakye it doesn't come up with an error, it just won't actually send

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies within your third line of code. What you do here is create a new Collection everytime someone joins. This means that the collection can never be `> 10` because it's always `1`.

To fix this simply create the Collection at the top of your index file and not inside a listener.

On a sidenote, I assume you want to create the collection to keep track of who is in your discord server. Thats not really a good idea because it will be newly created every time the bot restarts and since it only gets updated when someone joins or leaves it won't be accurate. A lot easier to use is the [`guild.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager) collection.

EDIT: This is how you would do something like that

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const guild = member.guild;
    const userlist = guild.members.cache.map(u => `\n${u.user.username}: ${u.user.id}`);
    guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "general").send("Welcome our new user!\n Users" + userlist);
})
```

Please keep in mind that this will return all members of the guild. You can only use the [`guildMembersChunk`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMembersChunk) listener to welcome multiple members and all of those need to come from the same guild which is rather unlikely.

Comment: Thanks, could you post an example of the correction?

Comment: Comes with with an error, find is not a function                       
                           guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "general").send("Welcome our new user!\n Users" + userlist);
                   ^

TypeError: guild.channels.find is not a function

Comment: you need to use `guild.members.cache`. See the Answer.